# Create 5000 directories with VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, directory

I want to create 5000 directories with the name of the directory being the counter.

Below is my code I want to use but this only create 1 directory for me, why is that?

```
 Dim Counter As Integer

 Counter = 1

 Do Until Counter = 5000

       FolderPath = "C:/pics/" + Counter.ToString() + "/"
       Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath)

 Loop

        Counter += 1
```

VB.NET or C# will do, I just want to run this once.

Comment: You might want to move the counter logic up into the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `counter+=1` inside of the do loop.  It probably creates the first directory but because counter never is incremented inside the loop it probably just overwrites itself.

Change to this:

```
Do Until Counter = 5000

       FolderPath = "C:/pics/" + Counter.ToString() + "/"
       Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath)
        Counter += 1
 Loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `do while` with integer, for integer and double types better use function `For`:

```
For Counter as Integer = 1 to 5000
   FolderPath = "C:/pics/" + Counter.ToString() + "/"
   Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath)
Next
```

P.S. in your case you need to move `counter+=1` before `loop` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a `For` loop for this:

```
For counter as Integer = 1 To 5000
    FolderPath = "C:/pics/" + counter.ToString() + "/"
    Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath)
End For
```